# Episerver Visitor groups not working

Tags: episerver, visitor-pattern

Are there any known issues (bugs) in EpiServer regarding Visitor groups? I can visualise the Visitor groups from the Visitor groups tab in Episerver; however, when I open a specific page and insert a control, then click the Personalize Content button to apply my custom group(s), I am unable to view my full list of visitor groups (in order to select one or several) - the list is empty.
I use Episerver 6 R2. How did you handle this? Thanks.

Comment: Is it a UI error? Which browser are you using? Any console errors?

Comment: Ted: I am using Chrome. No errors, the list just doesn't populate.

Comment: Weird, never seen that, but it's been a while since I worked on 6 R2. :/

Comment: Apparently, it's possible to apply the custom setting on Firefox and IE, and you can view it subsequently on Chrome, but I was looking for a more general solution that works on ALL browsers for applying the personalised content). Thanks, Ted!

Comment: Yeah, CMS 6 is only fully supported on IE and Firefox. :/